# Elementary OS ignoring suspend disable

Tags: settings, system, release-juno

In power settings, suspend is disabled. However, the PC still goes into a suspend state after approximately 30 minutes. This behavior does not happen under Ubuntu Budgie on another SSD in the same PC. This is a desktop, not a laptop.  Is the behavior intended, or is there a way to disable this that I'm not finding?

Comment: I also noticed this, even on beta. And now in a fresh final release, I has just now masked the services, and follow now how it works.

Answer (score 16):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/89

There's a workaround near the (current) bottom of the page:

> This problem is because the power settings are used from the gconf configuration of the user lightdm, and not the current user.
>   Just test:

```
sudo su
su - -s /bin/bash lightdm
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
```

> If you change the settings of the user lightdm, the problem disappears

A little further down, it says you need to set the key to "nothing" (still as the lightdm user):

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
```

You might get a message `No protocol specified`, which you can ignore.

Comment: After the last command I get back `No protocol specified`. Is this the expected result?

Comment: @Gabriel I also got that message, but it works for me nonetheless.

Comment: I'm having this problems since i remember.
Finally i can solve it with this tip , thank you .
I like elementary os because of its style and simplicity
i just added latest mesa from oibaf and latest liquorix kernel
and i can say i'm pretty satisfied with my system.
Now i'm gonna install it on my laptop too.
This bug was disabling me for making it my dail driver cause
i always leave my pc on downloading torrents,games from steam etc etc
I wish it will be fixed on future updates it should have to be fixed
cause its very old bug.

Comment: Don't use the Oibaf PPA! It does not package mesa releases but daily git snapshots. I think it's irresponsible of them that they removed the acoording disclaimer from the PPA description. Use the Ubuntu HWE packages, which privide updated mesa and kernel release packages.

Comment: I tried this solution on Elementary Hera, the computer doesn't suspend now, but I cannot use the sleep / shutdown function from the menu, only the power buttons turns off the pc.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I had set "Suspend when inactive" to "Never", but it would still suspend when idle.

Because I don't care to EVER put this system into suspend mode (automatically or otherwise), I also did another couple of things:

I set the power button action to "do nothing".

And I did this command from the [Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend), to completely disable any suspend actions:

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

Now it doesn't suspend itself. I suspect that the systemctl command was the specific thing that did the trick, but I haven't done any further tests to see whether the power button setting also helped.

Comment: BTW my understanding was that this issue was fixed in 5.1, but the bad suspend behavior persists in my setup after upgrading to 5.1.

Comment: My mistake, looks like we are waiting for this to merge: https://github.com/elementary/greeter/pull/343

Comment: I tried it and expected it to work on my system but it still suspends

Comment: The way I worked around the issue is simply after implementing those instructions to install Screensaver, then my screen doesn't shut down and I can recuperate my system.

Comment: Please add also the command to rollback the operation: `sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`. I used it on Hera and the computer didn't respond to suspend/halt anymore