# How to prevent computer from sleeping or suspending

Tags: suspend

I've installed the latest version of ElementaryOS (as of a few days ago) and am looking for a way to prevent it from falling asleep or suspending.  In `System Settings`->`Power` I've set "Suspend when inactive for:" to *Never*.  Anything else I need to set?

Comment: This sounds like a duplicate for https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/elementary-os-ignoring-suspend-disable/16613

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured this out.  The settings in `System Settings`->`Power` don't seem to make any difference, at least on my particular BIOS or motherboard or whatever.  However, this command will fix the problem and prevent the machine from ever sleeping:

`sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target`

Comment: That might be a bug; it should honor the power settings.

Answer (score 0):

did you set "Plugged In" OR "On Battery" ? they are different.

Comment: I don't see anything about plugged in or battery.  Note this is on a desktop computer, so perhaps the OS is aware of that and knows there's no battery?