# Prevent desktop from sleeping or suspending while using SSH

Tags: suspend, power, ssh

I have a desktop that has Elementary installed. I often use the desktop remotely, over SSH through local LAN or with [Tailscale](https://tailscale.com), but I am often disconnected from my session when using SSH. I found this [SE answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16817/how-to-prevent-computer-from-sleeping-or-suspending) about it disables suspending and sleeping completely.

Is there a way to disable suspend/sleep when using SSH?

Comment: I don't know anything about Tailscale. Does it offer you the chance to add a command to your login?

Comment: You should configure SSH on the server. More info here https://tinyurl.com/grbjqnb

Comment: I'm considering removing the Tailscale ref as it is not helpful. Tailscale is built on Wireguard but has a nice wrapper. I am trying to prevent suspend/sleep when I am connected remotely via SSH (no matter how I retrieved the IP)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `systemd-inhibit` to block sleep/suspend while you're running the command. This has the express benefit of being a dynamic solution, rather than masking the calls entirely.

Eg:
`systemd-inhibit --what=sleep --mode=block ssh`

I use this to stop my machines from shutting down while my backups are running. Once the command completes, it stops blocking sleep.