# Computer always Suspends when Its selected as Never

Tags: suspend, power, release-juno

I needed some help with the power options on Elementary OS Juno. In the power options I have selected that computer should never suspend and that only the monitor would turn off after 15mins.

No matter what it always suspends my computer after 40 or so minutes. I cant figure out how to solve this issue.

I am semi new to linux so please do not use crazy terminology otherwise I may not understand it.

Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: Solution is found. just wanted to update the solution in here incase people were searching for it.

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17419/16813