# Laptop doesn't suspend on lid close

Tags: release-juno, suspend, laptop

I have 2018 laptop with i5-8300h and Elementary OS 5. It doesn't suspend on lid close. However if I press button on the screen it suspends normally. I have tried to configure `logind.conf` but nothing changed. I also read a lot of different answers with the same questions, but nothing has helped.

Comment: Can you add details of what laptop you specifically have? You might also run `sudo less /var/log/lightdm/lightdm.log` to see whether there are any log entries related to what lightdm is thinking when it chooses not to suspend your laptop.

Answer (score 2):

More people seem to have the same issue: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/94

---

For people interesting in how to switch settings via console:

It might be related to an issue in the switchboard app of elementary: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/89

A workaround is explained here: [Elementary OS ignoring suspend disable](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/elementary-os-ignoring-suspend-disable/17419#17419)

In your case:

```
sudo su
su - -s /bin/bash lightdm

#check the values
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action

gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action

#set values eg. to suspend
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action suspend

dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action suspend
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, unfortunately, both commands ( on ac and on battery) show 'suspend'

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be of much help :-/
At least you know that the settings are correct...

I found this on github: https://github.com/elementary/switchboard-plug-power/issues/94

You can give a thumb up to show that you are also effected. Maybe you can give some helpful input there!

Comment: Do you have an external monitor attached during lid closed? Than you might have to set lid-close-suspend-with-external-monitor on true...

Comment: Thanks for help!) I don't use any external monitors.