# Cursor Size Won't Change with dconf

Tags: mouse, dconf

I want to make the size of the mouse pointer bigger. I tried using 
`dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/cursor-size 48`

Unfortunately, nothing happens. Even after a restart, the mouse looks the same. How could I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/18456/mouse-cursor-size-and-theme-not-adjustable/21094)

Fixed in latest update, you can change your cursor size in dconf

Also revert back theme is FIXED too

Tested

Path in changing cursor size is :
`org > gnome > desktop > interface > cursor-size`

`21` is best size for 4K HiDPi Screens

Theme can be applied in elementary-os tweak or gnome tweak no different