# Machine suspends even if it is not

Tags: networking

the elementary I use, goes into suspend mode even though I'm configuring not to do that.  Just leave the monitor set to shut down in 15 minutes.  The problem is that I always leave some activity running and when I use the machine, I see that the machine is suspended.

Comment: Already solution

Comment: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17419/18187

Answer (score 0):

This problem has now been resolved.  The link below has the answer.

[Solution](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/16519/18187)