# EOS Juno suspends while working

Tags: suspend

So Elementary OS Juno is suspending while working, playing on youtube or watching some movie online, playing radio, etc. Is there any way to bypass this but not to disable suspend in power settings? 
Baisicly i dont want for OS to suspend while working and while is not working I want him to do that... Did anyone found a solution without turning off in battery settings?

Answer (score 0):

Is the laptop on battery when suspending? or is it also happening when on power?

Try to disable suspend in:
/etc/systemd/sleep.conf

Set

```
#AllowSuspend=yes
```

to

```
AllowSuspend=yes
```

Comment: Also try: 

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/elementary-os-ignoring-suspend-disable