# How to prevent sleep/suspend while streaming music and videos

Tags: release-hera, suspend, audio, video-playback

When using Elementary (5.1.3) to stream music or video it goes to sleep after a while. I don't really want to change the power settings but would like Elementary to recognise when a stream is active and allow it to continue.
Other posts suggest solutions such as caffiene no longer work. Is there a way to get the behaviour I would like please?
With thanks in advance!

Steve

Comment: My question may be a duplicate of this question: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/19346/eos-juno-suspends-while-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is more on lightdm, I've already explained this before so I won't explain further and rather I'll just put steps here, This problem is because the power settings are used from the gconf configuration of the user lightdm, and not the current user. Just test:

```
sudo su
su - -s /bin/bash lightdm
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type
```

If these returns `suspend` then you can pass `nothing` like below to change it and you should be good.

```
dbus-launch gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type nothing
```

just ignore any output you get, `reboot` to take in effect, In my experience OS update 3 weeks ago reverted this setting which was in place since last year, but same worked again.

Also just verify `power settings` after reboot. incase you still having issues.

Comment: Thank you very much Raj, for taking the time to post this answer. It does seem to have resolved this issue for me.
Thank you again!

Comment: Oh dear, I spoke too soon! My audio stream stopped just a few minutes after posting the previous comment! :(

Comment: The first code returns `suspend` even after running the second command and rebooting.

Comment: Have run this again and audio does seem to continue now.
Thank you! Fingers crossed it is resolved!

Comment: You've to reboot once after change said settings.

Comment: I have found I have to reboot using `systemctl reboot -i'` i don't know if that has any relevance on whether this works or not?

Comment: Sounds like regular reboot, But glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like [keep awake](https://launchpad.net/keep.awake)