# Wifi keep disconnecting

Tags: wifi

I am new to Elementary OS, I have just installed it two days ago, Some reason my wifi disconnects after few minutes. I am using dell inspiron 7000. I never has this issue in Ubuntu before.

Comment: This is a similar issue and already explained here: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/24326/how-to-prevent-sleep-suspend-while-streaming-music-and-videos/24332#24332

Comment: That was fast, really appreciate for your time, I will try solution and update. Thank you.

Comment: @Raj Just followed steps you mentioned, I got output "Suspend" as you described, I will observe it and update here. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Looks like issue is been fixed, Thank you @Raj.

Comment: Solution very well explained here : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/24332/22703

Answer (score 0):

Some techs have pointed fingers at Dell's wifi card choice. I have had flaky wifi work when I switched to a Broadcom card from the Intel card.