# Elementary OS Juno - System keeps shutting down, even after changing power settings!

Tags: release-juno, suspend, shutdown

I tried changing the power settings to never turn off the display system is inactive, but it still seems to shut down in some time. Except for the power button option, all other settings are set to "Do Nothing". 
Can someone please help me here?

[image]

Comment: Question 1: does your system shut down after the exact same period every time?

Comment: Question 2: how will your system behave if you execute `shutdown -c` (cancel scheduled shutdown) command just after a fresh start?

Comment: Hi there and welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a bug and this question comes up regularly here. Please see this question and my answer there: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16519/elementary-os-ignoring-suspend-disable/